# Prove that $1+\frac{1}{8n}\sqrt{\pi_1n}<\frac{2.4.6\ldots(2n-2)(2n)}{1.3.5\ldots(2n-3)(2n-1)}<(1+\frac{1}{8n}+\frac{1}{128n^{2}})\sqrt{\pi_2n}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Within the confines of the O-level syllabus, prove that:

$$1+\dfrac{1}{8n}\sqrt{\pi_1n}<\dfrac{2.4.6\ldots(2n-2)(2n)}{1.3.5\ldots(2n-3)(2n-1)}<\left(1+\dfrac{1}{8n}+\dfrac{1}{128n^{2}}\right)\sqrt{\pi_2n}$$

for all positive integer $n$, where $\pi_1=3.141$ and $\pi_2=3.142$

Using A-level mathematics, show that the result remains true with $\pi_1=\pi_2=\pi$ where $\pi$ is the familiar constant associated with a circle.

This is a question found in Hammersley's "On the enfeeblement of mathematical skills by "Modern Mathematics" and by similar soft intellectual trash in schools and universities"

When I first look at this problem, I wonder if I can prove it via Wallis'product?
$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2n}{2n-1}.\dfrac{2n}{2n+1}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Why downvote this question?

Comment: I doubt whether Wallis's product has ever featured in an A-level (let alone O-level) syllabus.

Comment: Thanks, I am not familiar with British school curriculum. The author is an Englishman anyway.

Comment: You wrote "where $\pi_1=3.141$ and $\pi_1=3.142$". Did you mean the second variable to be $\pi_2$?

Comment: I don't understand your quesion. $\pi_2$ is the second number. Both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are numbers that sandwich $\pi$.

Comment: You wrote that the same variable, i.e., $\pi_1$, has $2$ different values of $3.141$ and $3.142$. This doesn't make sense. I was asking if you intended the second variable to be $\pi_2$ instead, i.e., change $\pi_1 = 3.142$ to $\pi_2 = 3.142$. Also, note if you wish for me to be notified that you've responded to me, you should use "@" followed by my name (note you can usually just type first letter or two & then press Tab to accept prompt) as I'll otherwise normally only be notified if nobody else has commented to your question. This is why it took me so long to see & respond to your comment.

Comment: @John Omielan: I have fixed the typo.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173253/hammersleys-wallis-type-questions

Answer (score -1):

$$
\dfrac{2.4.6\ldots(2n-2)(2n)}{1.3.5\ldots(2n-3)(2n-1)} = \dfrac{2n!}{(2n-1)!} = 2n \\ \therefore \;\; 1+\dfrac{1}{8n}\sqrt{\pi_1n}<\dfrac{2.4.6\ldots(2n-2)(2n)}{1.3.5\ldots(2n-3)(2n-1)}<\left(1+\dfrac{1}{8n}+\dfrac{1}{128n^{2}}\right)\sqrt{\pi_2n}
\\ = 1+\dfrac{1}{8n}\sqrt{\pi_1n}<2n<\left(1+\dfrac{1}{8n}+\dfrac{1}{128n^{2}}\right)\sqrt{\pi_2n}
$$

Considering the case of $$\pi_1 = \pi_2 = \pi$$ since this generality can be used for the other case too.

Splitting the inequalities into two,

\begin{align}
I_1: 
1+\dfrac{1}{8n}\sqrt{\pi n}<2n \\
1+\dfrac{1}{8\sqrt n}\sqrt{\pi}<2n \\
\dfrac{1}{8\sqrt n}\sqrt{\pi}<2n - 1 \\
\dfrac{1}{8}\sqrt{\pi}<(2n - 1)\cdot\sqrt n \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
Since n is a positive integer, minimum value of n is 1, which when substituted in \eqref{1} gives $$ 0.2215 < 1 $$ which is true.

\begin{align}
I_2:
2n<\left(1+\dfrac{1}{8n}+\dfrac{1}{128n^{2}}\right)\sqrt{\pi n}\\
\dfrac{2n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}<\left(1+\dfrac{1}{8n}+\dfrac{1}{128n^{2}}\right) \\
\dfrac{2n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} - 1<\left(\dfrac{1}{8n}+\dfrac{1}{128n^{2}}\right) \\
\dfrac{2n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} - 1<\dfrac{1}{8n}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{16n}\right)\\
\dfrac{2n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} - 1<\dfrac{1}{8n}\left(\dfrac{16n+1}{16n}\right)\\
(128n^{2})\cdot\dfrac{2\sqrt n}{\sqrt{\pi}} - 1< 16n+1\\
\dfrac{256n^{\frac{5}{2}}}{\sqrt \pi} - 128n^{2}<16n+1\\
\dfrac{256}{\sqrt \pi} < ( 128n^2 + 16n + 1 )\cdot n^{\frac{2}{5}} \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

Since n is a positive integer, minimum value of n is 1, which when substituted in \eqref{2} gives $$ 144.43 < 145 $$ which is true.

Comment: This [ $\dfrac{2.4.6\ldots(2n-2)(2n)}{1.3.5\ldots(2n-3)(2n-1)} = \dfrac{2n!}{(2n-1)!} = 2n$ ] is completely false (the numerator is the product of just even numbers up to $2n$ and not all the numbers as you assume). For example for $n=2$ we have $\frac{2\cdot 4}{1\cdot 3} = \frac{8}{3}$ which is not equal to $2n = 4$.

Comment: @Winther Oh right, I assumed it as n in my head, ugh all that work gone in trash.