# Hammersley's Wallis type questions

Tags: real-analysis

In Hammersley's article "On the enfeeblement of mathematical skills by `Modern Mathematics' and by similar soft intellectual trash in schools and universities" ( which can be found at http://www.inp.nsk.su/~silagadz/Hammersley_Modern_Mathematics.pdf ) he poses 16 problems of varying difficulty (starting at page 83). Problem 8 is the famous sofa problem, however my question concerns the first two.

I can solve the second but have to use the result of Gauss concerning the sum of a hypergeometric series as the ratio of two gamma functions. I am pretty sure that this was not in the A level syllabus in 1967 (though I might be wrong). So can anyone do this without resorting to such high powered maths? The bounds are very good.

As far as the first question is concerned I am at a loss. Not knowing exactly what was in the O level syllabus then doesn't help of course. Does anyone have any ideas.

Finally does anyone have access to copies of the bulletin where answers may possibly have been given?

The question [Prove that $1+\frac{1}{8n}\sqrt{\pi_1n}<\frac{2.4.6\ldots(2n-2)(2n)}{1.3.5\ldots(2n-3)(2n-1)}<(1+\frac{1}{8n}+\frac{1}{128n^{2}})\sqrt{\pi_2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138096/prove-that-1-frac18n-sqrt-pi-1n-frac2-4-6-ldots2n-22n1-3-5-ldots) is the first question but is still unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to both questions. The solution to the second depends on the solution to the first. So let's define for $n\ge1$
$$
A(n)=\frac{2.4.\dots.(2n-2).2n}{1.3.\dots.(2n-3)(2n-1)}\quad
L(n)=\left(1+\frac{1}{8n}\right)\sqrt{n}\quad
U(n)=\left(1+\frac{1}{8n}+\frac{1}{128n^2}\right)\sqrt{n}
$$
then we want to show
$$
L(n)\sqrt{3.141}<A(n)<U(n)\sqrt{3.142}.
$$
The aim is to show $\forall m,n\ge1$
$$
\frac{A(m)}{U(m)}<\frac{A(m+1)}{U(m+1)}<\frac{A(n+1)}{L(n+1)}<\frac{A(n)}{L(n)}
$$and we do this in three steps. Suppose $k\ge1$

1. $L(k)<U(k)\implies \frac{A(k)}{U(k)}<\frac{A(k)}{L(k)}$.
2. Expanding
   $$
   \left(\frac{A(k)}{L(k)}.\frac{L(k+1)}{A(k+1)}\right)^2-1
   $$gives$$
   \frac{p(k)}{q(k)}
   $$where $p(k)$ and $q(k)$ are polynomials in $k$ which are greater than $0$ for all $k\ge1$. The algebra needed for this is elementary if tedious. Hence $\forall k\ge1$
   $$\frac{A(k)}{L(k)}>\frac{A(k+1)}{L(k+1)}.
   $$
3. Expanding
   $$
   \left(\frac{A(k+1)}{U(k+1)}.\frac{U(k)}{A(k)}\right)^2-1
   $$gives$$
   \frac{p^\prime (k)}{q^\prime (k)}
   $$where $p^\prime (k)$ and $q^\prime (k)$ are polynomials in $k$ which are greater than $0$ for all $k\ge1$. The algebra needed for this is also elementary but considerably more tedious.  Hence $\forall k\ge1$
   $$\frac{A(k+1)}{U(k+1)}>\frac{A(k)}{U(k)}.
   $$

Putting these together gives the result  $\forall m,n\ge1$
$$
\frac{A(m)}{U(m)}<\frac{A(m+1)}{U(m+1)}<\frac{A(n+1)}{L(n+1)}<\frac{A(n)}{L(n)}.
$$
We now observe by direct calculation that$$\frac{A(11)}{L(11)}=\frac{2.4.6.\dots.22}{1.3.5.\dots.21}.\frac{88}{89\sqrt{11}}=1.772560516<\sqrt{3.142}$$and so $\forall n\ge1$ $$\frac{A(n)}{U(n)}<\sqrt{3.142}.$$
Similarly $$\frac{A(4)}{U(4)}=\frac{2.4.6.8}{1.3.5.7}.\frac{2048}{2113\sqrt{4}}=1.772321006>\sqrt{3.141}$$and so $\forall n\ge1$ $$\sqrt{3.141}<\frac{A(n)}{L(n)}.$$
The second question follows from observing that the sequences $$\left\{\frac{A(n)}{L(n)}\right\} and \left\{\frac{A(n)}{U(n)}\right\}$$ are bounded and monotonic and hence have a limit. We have$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A(n)}{L(n)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A(n)}{\sqrt{n}}.\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{8n}\right)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$ and similarly$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A(n)}{U(n)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$Hence for all $n\ge1$ $$\frac{A(n)}{U(n)}\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A(n)}{\sqrt{n}}\le\frac{A(n)}{L(n)}.$$ This limit is found by standard expansions (all of which were in the A level syllabus) of the integral$$I_{n}=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\sin^n xdx$$ by repeated integration by parts. The limit is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A(n)}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{\pi}$$ and the result follows.